# Finding matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ that satisfies $\mathbf{J=Q^TAQ}$ of skew-symmetric $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{J}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, skew-symmetric-matrices

Let $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{J}$ be real, full-rank, skew-symmetric, square matrices. If we know those matrices, can we find a real square matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ that satisfies $\mathbf{J=Q^TAQ}$?

Specifically, my questions are:

1. Is the existence of $\mathbf{Q}$ guaranteed?
2. If yes, is $\mathbf{Q}$ unique (i.e. only one possible solution)? If it’s not unique, how to find some of the solutions?

Comment: The dimension of the space should be even.

Comment: Also, you don't try to send $A$  directly to $J.$   Send each one to the same standard form, a string of 2 by 2 skew blocks along the diagonal.   There may be an algorithm...I have 4 by 4 worked out.

Comment: of course $Q$ isn't unique -- multiply it by $-I$.  In general it's useful to consider the stabilizer $Q^TJQ = J$ for symplectic $J$ and you get the symplectic group.

Comment: Meanwhile, in the second edition of Matrix Analysis by Horn and Johnson (2013), Problem 4.5.P2  on page 295 is to prove that two skew symmetric matrices $A,B$  of the same rank are related by $B = R^T  A R $   for some nonsingular $R.$  So yes, the existence of your $Q$  is guaranteed.

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you for bringing the theorem up. I was almost done with constructing such an $R$ from scratch, without knowing the theorem.

Comment: This is very basic. Every skew-symmetric matrix $A$ in any field $F$(with a zero diagonal if $\operatorname{char} F=2$) is congruent over $F$ to the canonical form $R\oplus\cdots\oplus R\oplus0$, where there are $\operatorname{rank}(A)/2$ copies of $R=\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&0}$. It follows that two skew-symmetric matrices are congruent to each other if and only if they have the same rank. Many older texts (such as Gelfand, Shilov, or Hoffman & Kunze) have covered this and this can be easily proved by mathematical induction.